# Query for a specific date with MongoDB and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Within a MongoDB Collection I have a Date object that records both the date and time of an event.  I am trying to query based on a specific date and to ignore the time i.e. show me all events for today.

**Model.js**

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({
eventName        : String,
eventDate        : Date, 
eventLocation    : String,
eventLocationGeo : String,
eventCreator     : ObjectId
});
```

My main **app.js** is looking for the date to come across in Unix Timestamp format.

```
//Get Events based on Unix Time Stamp Date
app.get('/events/date/:date', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
var user = req.user._id;
var date = req.params.date;
console.log('date - ' + date);
eventController.getEventsByDate(user, date, req, res);
});
```

**Typical REST call**

```
    http://localhost/events/date/1410764400
```

Most of the reference articles reference using the $gte and $lt but no where does it mention how to strip off the time so my queries end up pulling 24 hours based on the full Date AND time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `moment.unix(req.params.date).startOf('day').toDate()` and `moment.unix(req.params.date).endOf('day').toDate()` from the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/), which is phenomenally useful.

With just ECMAScript Date, you can do:

```
var start = new Date(req.params.date);
start.setHours(0);
start.setMinutes(0);
start.setSeconds(0);
start.setMilliseconds(0);
```