# Saving date in MongoDB getting offset even when providing time

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

I'll start by saying I know there are many timezone-related questions and answers out there. Maybe I'm just missing an obvious one.

I'm trying to save a date range pair in Mongo - a from date and a to date. I'd like the from date saved at time 00:00:00:00 so if I run a query looking for >=2017-08-14 all results will show.

My problem is even though I'm sending a date with time 00:00:00.000Z Mongo is actually saving it -400, which appears to be equivalent to EDT offset right now. This leads to me either correcting a lot on the client side, or just showing and querying incorrect data. Once I get the date right, I'd like to just ignore time all together in my queries.

This is the range I'm sending to MongoDB

```
daterange: [ { from: 2017-08-14T00:00:00.000Z, to: 2017-08-31T00:00:00.000Z } ],
```

This is how that range is getting stored in Mongo

```
from: 2017-08-13 20:00:00.000,
to: 2017-08-30 20:00:00.000
```

What super silly rookie mistake am I making? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: It was a silly mistake. This post helped solve it. [Query for a specific date with MongoDB and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854345/query-for-a-specific-date-with-mongodb-and-nodejs)

When I created the date with moment I Should've just done this:

```
moment(dateString).startOf('day')
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake. This post helped solve it. [Query for a specific date with MongoDB and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854345/query-for-a-specific-date-with-mongodb-and-nodejs)

When I created the date with moment I should've just done this:

```
moment(dateString).startOf('day');
```